# Process launched by ShellExecuteEx() doesn't return focus to parent window when terminated

Tags: winapi, mfc

I'm using ShellExecuteEx() to launch some program and WaitForSingleObject() to wait for the program to be terminated in OnInitDialog()(MFC). As you know, after OnInitDialog() returns main dialog appears. But, in my case the main dialog doesn't seem to get back its focus from the child process created in OnInitDialog() by ShellExecuteEx(). It appears, but not activated and not on top of the other windows. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Please show the code around ShellExecuteEx.

Comment: If your application is dialog based you can put "SetForegroundWindow()" after the call to WaitForSingleObject. But if it's a dialog of a non dialog based application then I didn't find a solution either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by moving ShellExecuteEx() function out of OnInitDialog(). I placed the function before the declaration of the dialog variable. I don't know why, but anyway it solved the problem.

Comment: OnInitDialog runs before the dialog is visible. Therefore, when the other program ends, your dialog is not eligible for focus because it is not visible. Also, you should be using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects so you continue responding to messages while waiting. Otherwise, you can deadlock with the program you are waiting for.